# Azure MARS agent software dependencies

Tags: azure, backup

What are the dependencies of the Azure backup agent, Azure backup server (such as the specific version of ".net framework" and any additional software) Can anyone list out these dependencies I can find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure backup server needs .NET framework 4.6, server should be join to a domain and SQL Server Standard.

For more information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup

Azure Backup agent needs Microsoft .NET framework 4.5 and windows PowerShell

For more information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault

Comment: While installing the Azure backup agent on windows server 2008 it also installed Microsoft Virtual server 2005 r2 sp1. Does this affect the working of running server or application on the server?